# Is Lilith mythos considered Oral Torah?

Tags: creation, adam

I was wondering what the rabbinical context for Lilith currently is. As far as what I understand of the oral tradition Lilith was Adam's first wife, equal in that she was also made of clay, but she betrayed him with the Serpent. She was then cast from the garden, became an evil to plague mankind, and Adam then was given Eve created from a rib instead of clay.

Is there still a common belief in Lilith? Is this considered canon?

Comment: Devan, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for bringing your question here! You could make the question a little stronger by [edit]ing in more information about where you've heard of this tradition. Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.

Comment: Legend only as far as I know.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23563/how-widespread-is-the-belief-that-adam-had-a-first-wife

Answer (score 0):

[As discussed previously](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23563/how-widespread-is-the-belief-that-adam-had-a-first-wife), there are one or two late, less-authoritative *midrashim* that discuss such a concept.

So I'd call it neither common nor canon.

If it was in either Talmud that would be a different story; it's not.

Comment: Is there a reason to post this again, when it is clearly a duplicate of the other question (as your answer acknowledges)?

Comment: What about the statement from Rabbi Chanina about sleeping in a house alone in Shabbos 151b? (There are other references to Lilith in the Gemara besides this one.)

Comment: If you learned the entire Tanach and Talmud, you would know there is a demon named Lilith. Nothing at all, however, that this Lilith began as a prototype human female who was rejected and replaced by Eve. *That's* the part that gets everyone attention.